# $uibModal close($value) callback always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

From my template, I use `ng-click="$widget.addItem()"` to trigger a `$uibModal`.

Everything works fine, opening, closing, etc.

The problem is, I can't get the `$modal.close($value)` callback value to work. The function itself works fine, the modal closes, and the promise success function is called. The problem is, it always returns `undefined`.

---

**Component controller**

```
app.component('list', {
    templateUrl: 'widgets/list.html',
    controllerAs: '$widget',
    controller: function($uibModal) {

        // Add item through modal
        this.addItem = function() {

            // Init and open $uibModal
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                component   : 'modalAddItem',
                size        : 'md'
            });

            // $uibModal promise
            modalInstance.result.then(function(params) {
                console.log(params)
                // ---> undefined 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Modal template**

```
<div class="modal-add-item">

    <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
        // Some template stuff here 
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="$modal.ok()">Ok</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Modal component**

```
app.component('modalAddItem', {
    templateUrl: 'widgets/modals/add-item.html',
    bindings: {
        resolve: '<',
        close: '&',
        dismiss: '&'
    },
    controllerAs: '$modal',
    controller: function ($scope) {

        this.ok = function() {
            this.close({item: 'picked item'});
        }

    }
});
```

---

Everything works fine. But whatever I try, the close function always returns `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use `$value` instead of item.

```
this.ok = function() {
  this.close({$value: 'picked item'});
}
```

> close - A method that can be used to close a modal, passing a result.
>   The result must be passed in this format: {$value: myResult}

[Angular UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: Oh wow, you literally have to use `$value` as key, I thought that was for demonstration purposes only. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no prob you're welcome :) actually  in angular the & binding expects the caller to pass a map as an argument where the key must match the original key, in this case it's angular that estabilish the key. take a look at how & binding work in depth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43378614/javascript-objects-as-function-arguments-in-angular-directive-properties/43379581#43379581

Comment: Ah, I was already wondering what the `&` binding did. Thanks for the explanation.